# codeigniter - form's action property - how to specify full app path in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i have the following javascript in my view:

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('switches/showknownvlans/'.$ip.'/'.$hardwaremodel);?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(returnDataFromController) {
    //alert(returnDataFromController.length);
    var htmlstring;
    var submitFormHTML;
    htmlstring = "some html stuff";

    for(i = 0; i < returnDataFromController.length; i++) {

    }
    submitFormHTML = "<form method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' action='controllerX/methodABC/"+ $('#ip').val() +"/" + $('#hardwaremodel').val() +"/" + $('#port').val() + "'><input type='text' id='newVlanID' style='width:5em;height:1.5em'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='submit' class='btn' id='saveVlan' style='width:10em;height:2em'>Reassign Vlan</button></form>";
    alert(submitFormHTML);
    $('#clientajaxcontainer').html(htmlstring);
    $('#newvlanform').html(submitFormHTML);
```

The path that I currently have defined for my form's "action" property in the "submitFormHTML" string is incorrect.  Instead of taking my user to "http://myserver/myapp/controllerX/methodABC/" with all the parameters, its appending "controllerX/methodABC/" to the end of the current URL. 
so if the user is at:

```
 http://myserver/mypp/controller23/method123/
```

when the click on the button to submit the form, they end up at:

```
 http://myserver/mypp/controller23/method123/controllerX/methodABC/
```

Is there a way to get either the site_url() or base_url in javascript?
Any suggestions?  Thanks for reading the post.

Edit:

As per someone's suggestion (I think it's a good idea) I've create a new .js file called "global.js" and I have one line in it:

```
var BASEPATH = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
```

This file is then included in my template PHP file for my view like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- aka HTML5 -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/global.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I've modified my javascript that craetes the form to look like: 
        submitFormHTML = "  Reassign Vlan";
        alert(submitFormHTML);

Edit2:

What's interesting is that when I define BASEPATH in the global.js, the URL my javascript ends up generating looks like this:

```
 http://myserver/myapp/index.php/switches/showportvlan/parm1/parm2/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url%28%29;?%3E/index.php/switches/changeportvlan/parm1/parm2/parm3.
```

As you can see, instead of interpretting the "", it just included the text as is.

But if i forget including a separate js file and just do this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
         var BASEPATH="<?php echo base_url();?>";
     </script>
```

it works just fine.

I can't see why the include file fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer to match your new question

**header.php**

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
 //global vars, can be used in any external js file
 var BASEPATH = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
 var IP       = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
</script>

<script src="assets/js/global.js"></script>
```

**global.js**

```
(function($){

   var formsObject = {
       init : function(){
           if($("form#id1"))
           {
              this.formOne; //run form one if id is present
           }
       },
       formOne : function(){
           var fOne = $("form#id1");

           fOne.submit(function(){
               var data = {
                  '' : '',
               }

               do_ajax(data);
           });

           var do_ajax = function(data){
                $.ajax({
                     url : BASEPATH + fOne.attr('action'),
                     //and so on
                });
           }
       }
   }

   //ready
   $(function(){
       formsObject.init();
   });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i'd like to try your suggestion.  I like the idea of the global vars.  Are you referring the ci index.php that is in the root of my app folder?  When i tried that i get an error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' - its dying on the opening script tag. Or did you mean that I should include a js file in the index.php?

Comment: Sorry not ci index.php rather the template file(default.php) or whatever you called it.

Comment: Philip, I've added link to a new "global.js" file in my header.php file which is included in every view.  It only has one line in it:  var BASEPATH = <?php echo base_url(); ?>;  But the BASEPATH var is empty.  No errors but no value either.

Comment: It needs to be in double quotes "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" because its a string.  Just seen your updated question.  the value does not go inside "src". let me update my answer

Comment: hey Philip, the value you're seeing inside my "src" is something else.  But I will change my global js to have double quotes around all of it to see if that helps.

Comment: philip, check out the Edit2 section in my post. I'm not sure I follow your entire post - still just trying to get the variable defined globally... I think you're 10 steps ahead of me!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16382/discussion-between-dot-and-philip)

Answer (score 0):

The action is actually being called correctly. Similarly to href attributes, if you start it without a slash (`/`) it will just append the value to the current page's uri, which is the behaviour you describe.

You have 2 options to refer to this script from the root of the HTTP HOST:

start the action attribute with a slash:

```
action="/controllerX/methodABC/"
```

or add the full path to your server, including protocol:

```
action="http://myserver/mypp/controllerX/methodABC/"
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I don't think the first option is correct.  At least, i can say that it's not working.  it takes me to "myserver/controllerX/methodABC". I'd prefer not to have to fully qualify the path if i don't have to.

Comment: Are you doing this on a local server? In this case, you're probably best using the second option, but generating it from `site_url()`. So you'll have `action="<?php echo site_url('controllerX/methodABC'); ?>"`.

Comment: I recommend not using `site_url()` throughout your entire site. It's much more convenient to call it once in html's `<base>` element, and you can write `href='controller/function'` throughout the entire site.