# POST data not being set? Codeigniter solution

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post

I think I have a simple bug somewhere but I can't see it!
In my view, I have the following javascript to create a form:

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/methodX/'.$ip.'/'.$hardwaremodel);?>",
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(returnDataFromController) {
    var htmlstring;
    var submitFormHTML;
    htmlstring = "<br><br><B>To reassign the port to a new vlan, click on a VlanId below and then click on the OK button</B><br><table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
    htmlstring = htmlstring + "<th>VlanId</th><th>Name</th>";
    for(i = 0; i < returnDataFromController.length; i++) {

    }
    submitFormHTML = "<form method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' action='/myapp/index.php/controllerABC/methodABC/"+ $('#ip').val() +"/" + $('#hardwaremodel').val() +"/" + $('#port').val() + "'><input type='text' id='newVlanID' style='width:5em;height:1.5em'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='submit' class='btn' id='saveVlan' style='width:10em;height:2em'>Reassign Vlan</button></form>";
    //alert(submitFormHTML);
    $('#clientajaxcontainer').html(htmlstring);
    $('#newvlanform').html(submitFormHTML);
```

It's the "submitFormHTML" string that builds the form.

And in my controller I have the following logic to check for the input: 
    public function methodABC()
    {

```
     if($_POST){
         echo 'I am here';
         $form = $this->input->post();
         var_dump($form);
         exit();
     }
     else {
         echo "false";
     }
```

It always print the "false".  I've also tried using:

```
print_r($this->input->post());
```

and

```
    echo $this->input->post('newID');
```

But I can't seem to get the data from my view into the controller. 
Can you see where I'm going wrong?  Thanks for the help.

**Edit:**

The page when rendered, creates the following HTML for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/myapp/index.php/switches/changeportvlan/11.11.11.11 /">
<input type='text' id='newVlanID' style='width:5em;height:1.5em'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="submit" class='btn' id='saveVlan' style='width:10em;height:2em'>Reassign Vlan</button>
</form>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the textbox is missing a "name" attribute.  "id" is not enough!

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
if ($this->input->post(Null, False)) {
   echo "I am here";
   $form = $this->input->post(Null, True); ## True for XSS-cleaning, which you probably want.
   exit();
}
else {
   echo "False";
}
```

You have to give `$this->input->post()` arguments. Moreover, never use `$_POST` in CodeIgniter.

Good luck

Comment: thanks for the response.  But that doesn't work either.  Still only prints out a "False".  I orginally only used the input but found another post on this site where someone suggested trying the $_POST for troubleshooting...

Comment: Just do this before any sort of `if` statement: `print_r($this->input->post(NULL, False);` You'll see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Also, PLEASE use `form_open()` to open the form, because you shouldn't use an absolute path for forms.

Comment: Use `<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit text');` after loading the [Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html). It saves the day.

Comment: Hey... re: the form_open(), in my view, I'm actually building this form via javascript.  But for the purposes of this post (to simplify) I just posted the resulting HTML.  Actually, maybe you'll have a comment on my previous post because it had to do with the path.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302757/codeigniter-forms-action-property-how-to-specify-full-app-path-in-javascrip

Comment: Make an HTML file and just submit a form to the URL, just to see if the method on the controller is working properly. Just a real quick, three-line file with a POST form.

Comment: david. i've already done that.  actually, the contents of my original post that just had the HTML...was from my test file - created in the manner that you are suggesting...Check out the updated post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have no idea why you don't get an http:// in your `<form action='`. You need to set your project URL in `/application/config/config.php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16384/discussion-between-dot-and-david)